# Return an array of all matching elements Javascript/React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have two arrays `authors` and `posts`. I want to return the posts arrays with the authors names not their emails, as seen below.

```
const authors = [
  {name: 'Thompson Smith', email: 'thompson@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'John Doe', email: 'doe@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Jane Coker', email: 'jane@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Mirabel Ekong', email: 'ekong@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Samuel Doe', email: 'samuel@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Moses Philips', email: 'moses@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Marcus Bowa', email: 'marcus@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Peter Touch', email: 'touch@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Benson Bruce', email: 'bruce@gmail.com'},
]

const posts = [
  { title: 'title one', authors: ['doe@gmail.com', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title two', authors: ['bruce@gmail.com', 'moses@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title three', authors: ['samuel@gmail.com', 'touch@gmail.com', 'bruce@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title four', authors: ['thompson@gmail.com', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com'] },
]
```

I want to return the posts with the actual name of the authors like this

```
 <div>
  <h2>{post.title}</h2>
  <p>
    <span>{post.author.name}</span>
    <span>{post.author.name}</span>
    <span>{post.author.name}</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Please how can I achieve this in react/javascript?

**EDIT:**
I forgot to add some really important parts of the question.

1. In the `posts` array, there are some that have the actual names of the authors (not emails) and these names does not occur in the authors array, for example;

   ```
    { title: 'title one', authors: ['Michael Johnson', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] }
   ```

In this case, I also want to retrieve the name `Michael Johnson` and retrieve the names of the rest of the authors from the authors array.

2. In the `authors` array, there are extra props that I want to retrieve, such as the `userId`and `avatar`. In essence the code looks like this;

```js
   const authors = [
  {name: 'Thompson Smith', email: 'thompson@gmail.com', userId: '001', avatar: '/avatar/1'},
  {name: 'John Doe', email: 'doe@gmail.com', userId: '002', avatar: '/avatar/2'},
  {name: 'Jane Coker', email: 'jane@gmail.com', userId: '003', avatar: '/avatar/3'},
  {name: 'Mirabel Ekong', email: 'ekong@gmail.com', userId: '004', avatar: '/avatar/4'},
  {name: 'Samuel Doe', email: 'samuel@gmail.com', userId: '005', avatar: '/avatar/5'},
  {name: 'Moses Philips', email: 'moses@gmail.com', userId: '006', avatar: '/avatar/6'},
  {name: 'Marcus Bowa', email: 'marcus@gmail.com', userId: '007', avatar: '/avatar/7'},
  {name: 'Peter Touch', email: 'touch@gmail.com', userId: '008', avatar: '/avatar/8'},
  {name: 'Benson Bruce', email: 'bruce@gmail.com', userId: '009', avatar: '/avatar'}
]

const posts = [
  { title: 'title one', authors: ['doe@gmail.com', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title two', authors: ['bruce@gmail.com', 'moses@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title three', authors: ['samuel@gmail.com', 'touch@gmail.com', 'bruce@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title four', authors: ['thompson@gmail.com', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title five', authors: ['michael Johnson', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title six', authors: ['michael Johnson', 'Jane Joshua', 'samuel@gmail.com'] },
]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```js
<div>
  <h2>{post.title}</h2>
  <ul>
    <li><Link to={userId}><Avatar src={avatar}/>{post.author.name}</Link></li>
    <li><Link to={userId}><Avatar src={avatar}/>{post.author.name}</Link></li>
    <li><Link to={userId}><Avatar src={avatar}/>{post.author.name}</Link></li>

//If the author does not exist in the authors array, should return
 <li><placeHolderAvatar />{post.author.name}</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please how do I retrieve these extra props?

Comment: After updating your requirements, can you also add the expected output now ?

Comment: @LakshyaThakur I now added the expected output. Thanks in anticipation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we can build a `map` for each `email` as key and `name` as value and then use the same to get a new `posts` array like so :-

```js
const authors = [{
    name: 'Thompson Smith',
    email: 'thompson@gmail.com',
    userId: '001',
    avatar: '/avatar/1'
  },
  {
    name: 'John Doe',
    email: 'doe@gmail.com',
    userId: '002',
    avatar: '/avatar/2'
  },
  {
    name: 'Jane Coker',
    email: 'jane@gmail.com',
    userId: '003',
    avatar: '/avatar/3'
  },
  {
    name: 'Mirabel Ekong',
    email: 'ekong@gmail.com',
    userId: '004',
    avatar: '/avatar/4'
  },
  {
    name: 'Samuel Doe',
    email: 'samuel@gmail.com',
    userId: '005',
    avatar: '/avatar/5'
  },
  {
    name: 'Moses Philips',
    email: 'moses@gmail.com',
    userId: '006',
    avatar: '/avatar/6'
  },
  {
    name: 'Marcus Bowa',
    email: 'marcus@gmail.com',
    userId: '007',
    avatar: '/avatar/7'
  },
  {
    name: 'Peter Touch',
    email: 'touch@gmail.com',
    userId: '008',
    avatar: '/avatar/8'
  },
  {
    name: 'Benson Bruce',
    email: 'bruce@gmail.com',
    userId: '009',
    avatar: '/avatar'
  }
]

const posts = [{
    title: 'title one',
    authors: ['doe@gmail.com', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com']
  },
  {
    title: 'title two',
    authors: ['bruce@gmail.com', 'moses@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com']
  },
  {
    title: 'title three',
    authors: ['samuel@gmail.com', 'touch@gmail.com', 'bruce@gmail.com']
  },
  {
    title: 'title four',
    authors: ['thompson@gmail.com', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com']
  },
  {
    title: 'title five',
    authors: ['michael Johnson', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com']
  },
  {
    title: 'title six',
    authors: ['michael Johnson', 'Jane Joshua', 'samuel@gmail.com']
  },
]

const nameEmailMap = authors.reduce((acc, {
  name,
  email,
  userId,
  avatar
}) => {
  acc[email] = {
    name,
    userId,
    avatar
  };
  return acc;
}, {})

const newPosts = posts.map(({
  title,
  authors
}) => ({
  title,
  authors: authors.map(entry => (nameEmailMap[entry] ? { ...nameEmailMap[entry]
  } : {
    name: entry
  }))
}));

console.log(newPosts);
```

Comment: This works exactly as I want, but there are some important parts of the question which I forgot to mention in the initial post, such as retrieving extra props in the authors array. I have now added more details in the original post. Can you please help with it? Thanks so much

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details. I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much Sir.

Answer (score 1):

This seems like an exercise in javascript `map` and `filter`.

Here's an example of how you could do it.  And a codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-brown-owf67

Also your email address arrays are formatted weirdly, and since you didn't indicate a reason for that in your question I interpreted it as a typo and fixed them.  YMMV.

```
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.map((p) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{p.title}</h2>
          <p>
            {p.authors
              .map((a) =>
                authors
                  .filter((author) => author.email === a)
                  .map((author) => author.name)
              )
              .map(a => (<span>{a}</span>))}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This works exactly as I want, but there are some important parts of the question which I forgot to mention in the initial post, such as retrieving extra props in the authors array. I have now added more details in the original post. Can you please help?

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details. I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

One way is to map the `posts` array into another variable.
Inside this map function you could use the `Array.filter` and `Array.some` methods to return the correct authors like so:

```
let mappedPosts = posts.map(post => {
    post.authors = authors.filter(author => post.authors.some(a => a === author.email));

    return post;
});
```

this would create the same array as your `posts` variable except that the authors array is now an array of objects with names and email properties.

By the way: while testing my approach, i noticed your `posts` array probably is not seperated correctly:

```
 { title: 'title one', authors: ['doe@gmail.com', 'ekong@gmail.com, marcus@gmail.com'] },
```

Should be:

```
{ title: 'title one', authors: ['doe@gmail.com', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
```

(notice the comma's i placed behind ekong@gmail.com and before marcus@gmail.com.

**Edit**

In react i would store the new variable in a state, while using the useEffect hook to look for changes in both the authors and posts array using the dependency array:

```
let [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (authors && posts) {
        setMappedPosts(posts.map(post => {
            post.authors = authors.filter(author => post.authors.some(a => a === author.email));
            return post;
        }));
    }
}, [authors, posts]);
```

basically the same except the React way.
Then you could loop through `mappedPosts` and render the authors directly instead of having to filter through a different array inside your JSX which IMO is not very neat.

**Edit 2**

From what i understand is that you want to check if either the email or the actual name of the author has a match inside the authors array with respect to the posts array.

This is actually quite easy to do, you just have to extend your statement inside the `some` function:

```
let [mappedPosts, setMappedPosts] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    if (authors && posts) {
        let foundPosts = posts.map(post => {
            post.authors = authors.filter(author => {
                return post.authors.some(a => {
                    return a === author.email || a === author.name;
                });
            });
            return post;
        });
        setMappedPosts(foundPosts);
    }
}, [authors, posts]);
```

If you didn't notice; i've changed up the code a little bit to make it more readable. (store the found posts inside a variable and pass that variable to the setState function instead of alltogether).

Comment: This seems like what I want to do, but the posts return with an empty array of authors. I don't know why. I edited my original post and added a detail explanation. Perhaps you could help

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details. I'll really appreciate your help

Comment: Added a possible solution to your new question underneath "edit 2"

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate method for filtering out authors and mapping their names like:

```
function findPostAuthors(post) {
    return authors
    .filter(({email}) => post.authors.includes(email))
    .map(({name}) => name);
}
```

Also, your `posts.authors` arrays, all have two items, you are missing `'` between second and third item.

In react you could use it, something like this:

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {posts.map((post) => (
        <div>
          <h2>{post.title}</h2>
          <p>
            {findPostAuthors(post)
              .map(author => (<span>{author}</span>))}
          </p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

This way you could ditch `.map` in `findPostAuthors` function, so it wouldn't loop too many times.

Comment: Thank you so much. This works exactly as I want, but there are some important parts of the question which I forgot to mention in the initial post, such as retrieving extra props in the authors array. I have now added more details in the original post. Can you me please help?

Comment: I have updated the original question with more details. I'll really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

If the need is just to create a new array, then here is a sample that converts the array to the desired outcome

```js
let authors = [
  {name: 'Thompson Smith', email: 'thompson@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'John Doe', email: 'doe@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Jane Coker', email: 'jane@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Mirabel Ekong', email: 'ekong@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Samuel Doe', email: 'samuel@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Moses Philips', email: 'moses@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Marcus Bowa', email: 'marcus@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Peter Touch', email: 'touch@gmail.com'},
  {name: 'Benson Bruce', email: 'bruce@gmail.com'},
]

let posts = [
  { title: 'title one', authors: ['Michael Johnson', 'ekong@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title two', authors: ['bruce@gmail.com', 'moses@gmail.com', 'marcus@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title three', authors: ['samuel@gmail.com', 'touch@gmail.com', 'bruce@gmail.com'] },
  { title: 'title four', authors: ['thompson@gmail.com', 'jane@gmail.com', 'samuel@gmail.com'] },
]

posts = posts.map(obj => ({ ...obj, authors: obj.authors.map(email => authors.find(auth => auth.email === email)?.name ? authors.find(auth => auth.email === email)?.name : email )}))

console.log(posts)
```

Comment: This works exactly as I want, but there are some important parts of the question which I forgot to mention in the initial post, such as retrieving extra props in the authors array. I have now added more details in the original post. Can you please help with it?

Comment: @BigBros I updated my answer but i didnt udnerstand the second part. how is the desired output of posts with these new props that you want? please give us an example

Comment: Thanks very much. I now updated the original question to include the desired output. Thanks in anticipation